My VBA code keeps crashing my file and causing it to not respond
This code causes my file to crash if I select "-" from a dropdown list within my worksheet.  A timestamp gets implemented when "Yes" is selected however, it crashes when I select "-".  What am I missing?
The dropdown list contains 2 options:
-, Yes
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

On Error GoTo Handler
If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")
    
ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "-" Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = ""
    
End If
Handler:


End Sub


This one looks almost exactly what you want.


Your code may cause an infinite loop. eg. Cell A1 is changed, ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = .. triggers Change event again. and so on ...

Application.EnableEvents = False is necessary if any cells are changed in Change event code.

btw, You'd better use Target.Value instead of ActiveCell.Value.


Microsoft documentation:

Application.EnableEvents property (Excel)

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    On Error GoTo Handler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If ActiveCell.Value = "Yes" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")
        
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = "-" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = ""
        
    End If
Handler:
    
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub


Why is Target.Value a better option instead of ActiveCell.Value?

Target argument is the change cells (Range object). Activecell is always a cell on sheet. The changed range might be multiple cells.
